# Installing cable trunking on ceiling without damaging the ceiling paper

Tags: ceiling

I'm renting. I need to install [this trunking](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004GLCLK6/ref=oh_details_o06_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) on the ceiling for my projector's cables. In that room, ceiling is covered with wallpaper. If I use the adhesive feature that comes with it, I'm afraid that the day I move out and remove trunking, wallpaper will come with it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'd ask the owner.

Comment: Ditto. Structural changes to rented property, including installing things to ceilings is always a problem. If you are installing the projector from the ceiling on a bracket you may want to reconsider even that.

Comment: Wallpaper on the ceiling? Yuck, maybe it SHOULD be "accidentally damaged". :)  On a serious note, I've used the 3M Command scripts and was impressed by their ability to be cleanly removed (though I removed after only a few months), but I'm not sure if it would work as well on wallpaper. I'm confident at the worst it would do the same and most likely less damage than the adhesive usually on those conduits, but you'd have to weigh that risk considering your rental agreement.

Comment: Small screws leave small holes which are ready to conceal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3M command strips have been nice to me, even on wallpaper. If the wallpaper isn't tool old and it's in good condition, I recommend them.

Comment: Agreed.  While the 3M Command Strips (http://www.amazon.com/Command-Decorating-Clips-Value-40-Clip/dp/B000M3YGHS0) look similar to the double-sided sticky tape which tears everything, they actually have a different adhesive that holds well but then releases with no damage to any surface I've tried them on so far.  Excellent product.

Comment: Link doesn't work